# The same newsletter mail randomly sent to the registered customers

Tags: php, newsletter

My website built in bespoke n-retail coding based on PHP. Currently, I am having an issue whereby the same newsletter message randomly sent to my registered customers. 
Where in the file manager I need to check to find the issue. It must be a bug somewhere.

Comment: Would you provide more information? Without details (code sample, for instance), our answers would be just guesses on what could be the problem...

Comment: on the send_letter.php below code is running to send the letter      
#SELECT mail_id, customer_id, site_id from temp_mails order by mail_id LIMIT 40  when this runs it only generates the same newsletter even though it has been since changed to another newsletter and saved. I do not know where to look to find this newsletter the current cron job with below details seems running ok /usr/bin/wget -q http://www.mywebsite.com/mysite/send_letter.php >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: In error.log file I also found this:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead then this: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant customer_id - assumed 'customer_id' on Line 91

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibility 
 1. Newsletter is send from admin side 
 2. Cron job

You need to check both files so u get then bug, also provide more information so we can help you.

Comment: I have admin access and can see many letter_send.php files ran before but all have the same details. Not sure where I can trace the issue down.